# New Line Character not working in Formatted output in Pygame Window

Tags: python, pygame

I'm printing a formatted text in Pygame window. The full text is printing properly except a new line character(`'\n'`) I want to put between two values. The new line is coming out as a box, like printing an UNICODE character on non-UNICODE area. 
Anyway, take a look:

```
def updateScoreBoard():
     font=pygame.font.SysFont(None,14)
     text=font.render('Score: %05d \n Egg Caught: %03d' %(SCORE,EGGSCAUGHT),True,pygame.Color(255,255,255))
     textRect=text.get_rect()
     mainSurface.blit(text,textRect)
```

what I get as result,[image]

See the box between zeroes and the 'Egg'?
Then I updated the code with this:

```
NEWLINE='\n'
def updateScoreBoard():
     font=pygame.font.SysFont(None,14)
     text=font.render('Score: %05d %s Egg Caught: %03d' %(SCORE,NEWLINE,EGGSCAUGHT),True,pygame.Color(255,255,255))
     textRect=text.get_rect()
     mainSurface.blit(text,textRect)
```

Still same result. What I do now?

Comment: You can try changing your font to Arial `font=pygame.font.SysFont('Arial',14)`. Other that that everything looks fine.

Comment: fine? the 'Egg Caught' string should be in the next line, but giving a box instead! That's not fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

PyGame doc: [Font.render()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render)

> The text can only be a single line: newline characters are not rendered.

Comment: so my only option is to take another font/surface object to print the next line. Right?

Comment: yes, you have to `render()` next line and `blit()` it on `mainSurface` - you can move line down by changing `textRect.y`. Probably both lines should have the same height so you could try `textRect.y += textRect.height + some_margin`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution may be as the following.

```
def updateScoreBoard():
     font=pygame.font.SysFont(None,14)
     text=font.render('Score: %05d' (SCORE),True,pygame.Color(255,255,255))
     xl, ytop, xr, ybottom = textRect = text.get_rect()
     mainSurface.blit(text,textRect)

     text=font.render('Egg Caught: %03d' (EGGSCAUGHT), True, pygame.Color(255,255,255))
     xl, yt, xr, yb = textRect = text.get_rect()
     yt += (int(ybottom * 1.5) + ytop)
     yb += (int(ybottom * 1.5) + ytop)
     textRect = xl, yt, xr, yb
     mainSurface.blit(text,textRect)
```